# How can I add jdbc parameter that added new parameter of aws athena query engine 3 while using dbeaver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, dbeaver, amazon-athena

I Know that query reuse feature was recently added in aws athena.
The aws webconsole confirmed this operation.
But I cant' use this operation in dbeaver.
I tried to changed jdbc url parameter like (jdbc:athena?param1=val1..) but It didn't working.

the parameter is

```
enableResultReuse=1
ageforResultReuse=60
```

has anyone solved this problem ??

reference) https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/big-data/reduce-cost-and-improve-query-performance-with-amazon-athena-query-result-reuse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding both parameters to Athena Driver properties (in connection settings) in DBeaver:
[image: driver properties]

Comment: and I replace latest jdbc driver in dbeaver..